# downloading multiple files using Ihttphandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, ihttphandler

Greatings!

I'm working on a reporting script which runs a number of reports (pdf) on button click. The reports are created on the web server then I'd like the user to be given the option to download the files. I have worked out the script for downloading one file from the server. But I'm not sure how to download multiple files? (there will probably be about 50)

After I run one report I redirect the user to a http handler script.

```
Response.Redirect("Download.ashx?ReportName=" + "WeeklySummary.pdf");

public class Download : IHttpHandler {


public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{


   StringBuilder sbSavePath = new StringBuilder();
   sbSavePath.Append(DateTime.Now.Day);
   sbSavePath.Append("-");
   sbSavePath.Append(DateTime.Now.Month);
   sbSavePath.Append("-");
   sbSavePath.Append(DateTime.Now.Year);

    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    HttpResponse objResponce = context.Response;
    String test = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ReportName"];
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + test);
    objResponce.WriteFile(context.Server.MapPath(@"Reports\" + sbSavePath + @"\" + test));    
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

}
public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } } 

}
```

Thanks in advance, please let me know if you'd like to see any more of my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 options I see right away is the obvious one to simply call the HTTP Handler repeatedly.  Another one would be to zip them on the server and send a zip file across the wire.  You could use the built in [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) class to accomplish this.

Also, you'll want to add some code in your handler to clean up those temp files once they're downloaded.

Comment: I had thought about just caling the HTTP Headler loads of times but wasn't sure if there was a better way to do it or not. Think I'll zip them. Thanks for the link!